# how to grant network access to mongo atlas to a EKS deployment

Tags: kubernetes, node.js, mongodb, amazon-eks

problem:

I have an app running on a EKS cluster that needs to connect with a mongodb atlas database.

I must grant the app running on the EKS cluster network access by entering its IP address.

I do not know the IP address of the service / deployment of the app inside the cluster.